# How to check if debezium snapshot is complete

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I need to add more tables to `table.whitelist` in the Debezium Postgres connector. I found an approach mentioned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129060/2388940). It suggests that:

> When snapshot is completed then start the original connector with updated whitelist table list

But how can I find out if the snapshot is complete?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. You can check Kafka Connect logs OR read the boolean value of `payload.source.snapshot` in the latest event received OR use JMX where every connector's MBean has the [SnapshotCompleted](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#connectors-snaps-metric-snapshotcompleted_mysql) boolean property.

Answer (score 0):

Tail the `connect.offsets.storage` topic used by the Connect cluster and note down  the `server.id` specified in the connector.

For a complete initial snapshot, you should be seeing the following entry just post the snapshot completion.

```json
{ 
    "file":"my-database-bin.000004",
    "pos":143
}
```

As it is processing the events and catches up with the most recent binlog, it will update the status of the offsets against the server id.

```json
{
    "ts_sec": 1610704790,
    "file": "my-database-bin.000004",
    "row": 2,
    "pos": 134,
    "server_id": 2001186
    ...
}
```

The fact that it is now catching up with the master binlog and committing the offsets **is a confirmation** that the snapshot is done because only once the snapshot is completed does the connector watch against the source offset.